# How to add dll files from windows\syswow64 folder when publishing

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 application uses certain dll files that are located in the C:\Windows\syswow64 folder.
How can I include these files in the publisher so when it is installed on a different computer it adds these dll files to the correct folder?

thanks

Comment: The vast majority of the files in that folder should never be copied because they belong to the operating system.  If some kind of installer put them there then running that installer on the target machine is the correct way to do it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm working on an existing project and I received those dll files with the instruction to place them there. They all seem to be used for audio and video stuff (what they should do in my application) and I don't have a clue what software was used to install them. A quick google also doesn't show any usefull results.
The fillesnames are avcodec-53.dll, avdevice-53.dll, avfilter-2.dll, avformat-53.dll, avutil-51.dll, postproc-52.dll, swresample-0.dll and swscale-2.dll

Comment: Well, that was not a good idea.  Just don't screw up the user's machine the same way, he won't be happy.  Add them to your project with Project > Add Existing Item and set their Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy if newer".  Rebuild and they will be copied to your project's bin\Release directory.  Now it is simple and safe.

Comment: Try to install the right verion of .netframework and ffmpeg codec on your new computer.